# What are different between perf with event and without event?

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, performance-testing

I want to profile the run time and some information about a program create by myself.

I'm using the Linux tool - `perf` to measure the run time.

the command I used is like below:

```
$ perf stat -r 10000 ./program > /dev/null

 Performance counter stats for './program' (10000 runs):

          2.510453      task-clock (msec)         #    0.946 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.04% )
                 0      context-switches          #    0.002 K/sec                    ( +- 15.59% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
                50      page-faults               #    0.020 M/sec                    ( +-  0.02% )
           9237800      cycles                    #    3.680 GHz                      ( +-  0.00% )
           4011695      instructions              #    0.43  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.00% )
            689371      branches                  #  274.600 M/sec                    ( +-  0.00% )
              5144      branch-misses             #    0.75% of all branches          ( +-  0.03% )

       0.002653910 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.04% )
```

And then I using the `-e` flag to customize the events by myself.

```
$ perf stat -r 10000 -e cache-misses ./program > /dev/null

 Performance counter stats for './program' (10000 runs):

               941      cache-misses                                                  ( +-  0.69% )

       0.003506780 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.25% )
```

You can see that the run time of two command are totally different. The run time of command with event flag is slower than the one without the flag.

Why is that happened? And which run time of command is same as the run time of real user?

Comment: "You can see that the run time of two command are totally different." - I don't find that run times `0.002653910` and `0.003506780` are "totally different": they differ less in 1.5 times. It could result of the machine workload changings between the tests.

Comment: Exactly as @Tsyvarev states, it's usually pretty normal to get different results between different runs. If you really want, you could create a script to measure the result of 1000 runs and calculate mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Measuring the cache misses for a program lasting 2 ms is not accurate. Try with a longer benchmark. Running perf can impact this since the path taken by the processor will not be the same (perf needs to store informations which impact the behaviour of the cache)